# How to show Delta (Δ) symbol in generated pdf file without using font-extensions?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I need to show delta symbol in this text field expression:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_ESERCIZIO}]</textFieldExpression>
```

In order to show the greek symbol inside the PFD as well. How can I do that?

I cannot use *font extensions* feature. I need to do that by changing something in the code.

I tried to insert this code `&#916;` and other one, but without any result.

Comment: `I tried to insert this code Δ and other one, but with no result.` - What expression did you try? What do you mean `with no result`?

Comment: Did you try to show delta with help of *html* markup as `&#916;` (`&Delta;`) code?

Comment: yes, I tried both! I can see the symbol in the report preview, but not in the PDF.

Comment: Looks like fonts issue. You should post the sample (textField declaration) of your best try

Comment: Another possibility is to use a PNG image, or embedded vector graphic.

Comment: @Dave yeah I like that solution, since you can't use font-extensions, you can't use fonts, use an image instead :D

Comment: @DaveJarvis I like this solution! I only need to correctly fit the image inside my table cell! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use font extensions feature

With this requirement you will **not** be able to generate pdf correctly, you will always risk and often find as in this case export inconsistency (since font and the text encoding is not specified).

The simplest way to add font-extensions is to use download jasper-reports default font-extensions, [jasperreports-fonts](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts)

Use one of the jasper reports default fonts es. "DejaVu Sans" in your `textField`

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="5d73c008-19d3-42f3-bb64-9d4d90656867"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Δ"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

And enjoy the correct rendering and use of the library[image: Result]

<sup>You could do a desperate try to set the deprecated `pdfFontName` and `pdfEncoding` font attributes to see if you have some font installed on your computer that will correctly render Δ, but why? NO NO NO do not do this, add font-extensions</sup>